# MSGrapClient request credentials on purpose

Tags: spfx-webparts

Is there a special way to ask a user for credentials when my app is initializing. For example, the app consists of several stages and at the 3-rd stage a user send ms graph request and if he's not authenticated he will be redirected and lose the data he filled during the first 2 stages. I assume that I can do just an empty ms graph request at the beginning but may be there is a special way for this.